How to match UserID values beetween two different tables, and feed table 1 with values from table 2
I did it easily on EXCEL using VLOOKUP, but I´m too newbie on KustoQuery :-)
Can someone give me some hints about how to do this?:
Both tables shares the same UserId_s values.
I need to extend table 1 with UserPrincipalName and Country values from table 2.
Table 2 looks like:
Id_s
0 - 5da0e439-54cb-4607-9ef5-0a1ace71e93e
1 - 755dbf3a-5f57-4d93-a245-e8c2ab0baa6e
UserPrincipalName_s
0 - Max.Power@company.com
1 - Me.Myselft@company.com
Country_s
0 - South Africa
1 - United Kingdom

Thank you so much!
I assume Join and Lookup must be involved but I´m not finding the proper way to do it, nor any similar example on the web.

check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with

Yes, you need to use join operator on those tables. Join should happen on matching Id_s column.
Below is the code.
Table1
| join kind=leftouter (
    Table2
) on Id_s

The kind=leftouter parameter specifies to perform a left outer join, which will include all rows from Table1 and only matching rows from Table2. This join type is the equivalent of vlookup in excel. You can change the join type based on your requirement. Refer the MS document on join operator
demo
